# opos scale, ResultCodeExtended values

Tags: scale, opos

when I put on a scale a weight bigger than the maximum weight, I get back
Returncode=114
Device. ResultCodeExtended=201
I think 114 means OPOS_E_EXTENDED, meaning check  the extended code, which is 201.
But I don’t know what 201 means

Answer (score 1):

The content of the number indicates exactly the situation of the question.
Please refer to these materials.

[UNIFIEDPOS](https://www.omg.org/retail/unified-pos.htm)

- Download the current version 1.14.1 of UnifiedPOS

```
readWeight Method
...
E_EXTENDED ErrorCodeExtended = ESCAL_OVERWEIGHT:  
           The weight was over MaximumWeight.  
           This can only be returned if AsyncMode is false.
```

---

[MCS: OPOS Common Control Objects - Current Version](http://monroecs.com/oposccos_current.htm)

[OpenPOS for OLE Common Control Objects Version 1.16](https://github.com/kunif/OPOS-CCO)
[OPOS-CCO/Common/Opos/OposScal.h](https://github.com/kunif/OPOS-CCO/blob/v1.16.0/Common/Opos/OposScal.h)

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// "ResultCodeExtended" Property Constants
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const LONG OPOS_ESCAL_OVERWEIGHT        = 201; // ReadWeight
const LONG OPOS_ESCAL_UNDER_ZERO        = 202; // ReadWeight (added in 1.9)
const LONG OPOS_ESCAL_SAME_WEIGHT       = 203; // ReadWeight (added in 1.9)
```